# Azure NotificationHub - General questions

Tags: azure-mobile-services, azure-active-directory, azure-notificationhub

It looks like tags are strings like "userID_123", "tag2", "sports" etc.  Is this true, or are they really key/value pairs because in the Azure dashboard I see a Tags button which gives me the ability to create Key/Value Pairs

[image]

Also, is there a web to send the pushes out using a web api?  Previously I did this using Parse, and was able to leverage their REST api to send from within a ColdFusion application using the  tags.  How can I accomplish this using Azure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tags that you see in Portal are entity tags not the device level tags. Azure Notification Hub currently supports only boolean tags like "sports", "userid_123" at the device level. They are not key value pairs.

Yes, Notification Hub does support REST API for sending push notifications. Here is MSDN documentation link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495827.aspx